# GAE Go and long polling?

Tags: google-app-engine, function, web-applications, go, long-polling

What is an efficient way of implementing long polling in Golang on Google App Engine? I came across [this code](https://gist.github.com/1039785), but it was made for a non-GAE application (uses channels and goroutines, which as far as I know aren't the best for GAE).

EDIT:

I specifically need to implement long polling for an application I don't control (see [this](https://deepbit.net/longpolling.php) reference), thus the use of [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/channel/) as a substitution for polling will not do.

Comment: Are you trying to long-poll something, or write an app that will be long-polled?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to write a bitcoin miner on App Engine, I'm sorry to say it's not a good choice of platform. App Engine is built primarily for implementing webapps and interactive sites, not bulk computation.

Comment: @NickJohnson I'm trying to write an app that will be long-polled. I'm not intending on writing a miner, but a mining pool. I already have the basic functionality and managed to mine some testnet blocks - http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/block/0000000006a4db9a09418f3f28b7b67dca30e691f9bf7cfa60ae034cc77ed003 .

Comment: In that case, your only real option is to implement long polling yourself. That will really eat through your instance hours, though, even with multithreading on.

Answer (score 2):

Frontend instance are subject to a 60s request deadline for http request.

You can try implementing long polling using [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/backends/overview) as they don't suffer the same limitation (infinite deadline).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/channel/).

Comment: Channel API is more of a substitution for polling in general, whereas I need to specifically create long polling for communicating with an application that I don't control.

Comment: Then you're out of luck - GAE has a request time limit of 30 seconds, which is rather problematic for long polling.

Comment: @Amber The time limit hasn't been 30 seconds for some time. It's 60 seconds for frontend requests, 10 minutes for task queue tasks, unlimited for backends, and up to 10 minutes for outgoing urlfetches.

Comment: Ah, okay, I'm a little out of date on the current time limits. That said, 60 seconds still poses the same problem (and long polling would be hitting the frontend timeout, so the others are irrelevant).